# Using div tag page redirection

Tags: html

help me.page redirection to the particular section of the page is working properly in firefox and internet explorer.But not working in chrome.i make the redirection by giving id in div tag.what i do

Comment: For start you should show us your code, so we can see what is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]